# Problem mixing VBScript and Compound Component Templates on a page

Tags: templating, vbscript

I'm trying to use a mix of VBScript CT's and a couple of new (albeit very basic) Compound CT's on my very old, complex legacy VBScript PT (!!) but the presence of the Compound CT's is causing Tridion to write out the compLink declaration at the top of my PT:

```
<% Dim compLink %>
<% Set compLink = Server.CreateObject("cd_link.ComponentLink") %>
```

This is already taken care of and **in the correct place under the @ command** using a different variable name for the other VBScript links.

Removing the Default Finish Actions from my Compound CT doesn't help as it's the LinkResolver C# fragment which is manipulating the links.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated although I know I could have simply rewritten the DWT into VBScript in the time it's taken me to compose this post! :)

Comment: That's interesting - maybe write a quick tbb to strip it out?

Comment: Never tried it,but i find one question which may give you some pointers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052188/is-it-possible-to-intermix-modular-templating-and-legacy-vbscript-ct

Answer (score 1):

While mixing Template languages is supported and working, it doesn't mean they complement eachother completely.

When mixing the two, first of all you should definitely see it as a temporary solution while in migration to the newer model. You should also consider handling things like Component Link object declaration a bit smarter, so not making it available by default, but depending it on whether you actually use it or not (like the Compound CT is doing by default).

One last remark, while it may sound easier to rewrite your DWT into VBScript, I think you should recognize the fact that VBScript is deprecated. Learning a new templating language will take some time, but once that is done, there are a lot of benefits you will get out of that newer technology too.